# How to assign two refs to same element

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd, react-tsx

Here I am trying to assign React dnd "drag" ref to existing ref but it is not happening, can any one please help me.

````
  const refs = useRef<(HTMLDivElement | null)[][]>([]);
const [{ isDragging }, drag] = useDrag(() => ({
    type: ItemType.item,
    collect: (monitor) => ({
      isDragging: !!monitor.isDragging(),
    }),
  }));
  for (let curRow = 1; curRow <= props.row; curRow++) {
    for (let curCol = 1; curCol <= props.col; curCol++) {
      columns.push(
        <div
          onClickCapture={() => moseHandler(curRow, curCol)}


          ref={(el) => {      //----------------------------->for this ref I want to assign Drag ref
            refs.current[curRow] = refs.current[curRow] || [];
            refs.current[curRow][curCol] = el;
          }} 


          className="el1"
          id={`${curRow}${curCol}`}
          key={`${curRow}${curCol}${generateKey(curCol)}`}
        >
         {`${curRow}${curCol}`}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }```
````

Answer (score 2):

> **How do I combine several drag sources and drop targets in a single**
> component? Both useDragand useDropreturn functions that may be chained
> against within a node's ref function. For example:
>
> const [, drag] = useDrag(...args) const [, drop] = useDrop(...args)
>
> return <div ref={(node) => drag(drop(node))}>

https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/faq

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`react-merge-refs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-merge-refs) to assign react-dnd's `drop` ref and the the ref you created onto the same element.